# c++ forward variadac function arguments to a class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

In C++, is there a way to define a function that takes N number of random arguments (number and parameter types could be anything) and in that function, instantiates a class who's constructor expects those arguments. In pseudo-code, something like:

```
class ClassType {
   ClassType(int, string){}
};

void func(Args ...) {
  ClassType A(Args);
}
```

And better yet, define a function pointer for "func"

Comment: yes it is possible. Note that "is it possible?" questions tend to lead to not so interesting answers. In this case it is just "Yes". Did you try something and encountered a problem? Do you have some real code that produces a compiler error?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: Fair. I do not have code that I tried and did not work. I'm at a lost as to where to even begin. Let me re-phrase the question: Would someone be so kind as to post an example of how to do this?

Comment: sorry, sometimes I am going a too far with critizising questions. A bit of motivation would help to answer, but it isnt strictly necessary. The question can be answered as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Output of this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct ClassType {
   ClassType(int a, std::string b){
       std::cout << a << b;
   }
};

template <typename...Args>
void func(Args&& ... args) {
  ClassType A(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    func(12,std::string("foo"));
}
```

is

```
12foo
```

However, it isnt quite clear why you want `func` to be variadic when `ClassType`s constructor only accepts `int,string`. Calling `func` with any other combination will fail.

> And better yet, define a function pointer for "func"

You cannot have a function pointer to a template (you also cannot have a function pointer to a whole set of overloads). Thats not how function pointers work. What you can do is taking a function pointer to one particular instantiation of `func`:

```
auto fptr = &func<int,std::string>;
```

If you need some function like object that you can pass around then you can use a generic lambda instead of a bare function pointer (since C++17 I believe):

```
auto flamb = [](auto&&...args){ func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
```

This works because the lambda is of some type (albeit unnamed and unspecified) and only its `operator()` is templated. Hence you can pass such lambda around and only when actually calling it the respective `operator()` is instantiated. Though, also with that you can only call it with the right parameters (`int` and `std::string`).

Comment: Thank you. Perfect response.

Comment: Just to nitpick - that lambda probably should also forward its arguments.

Comment: @Quimby can you explain why `decltype(args)` in the lambda but not in `func` ? Unfortuantely `std::forward` is something that is off the table for what I write daily (thats why I am usually careful with including it in my answers)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Of course. Usage of `std::forward<Args>(args)` in `func` is correct - `Args&&` in parameters denotes a universal reference, it uses reference collapsing rules to encode whether the param is l-value or r-value. `std::forward` uses this encoded `Args` type to move r-values only. So, `func` is correct as it is currently written. But lambda first took the arguments by value, not as univ.refs., second `std::forward` needs the type and lambda hides it in `auto`. We do no know `Args` in lambda, so we use  `decltype(args)` to retrieve it back.

Comment: @Quimby oh right, there is no `Args` in the lambda :). Thanks for the explanation